# In the following example, what would be the best epoch to use to avoid overfitting?

Tags: machine-learning, keras, deep-learning, data-science, training-data

I have a 8-layer fully connected neural network whose training is providing the following accuracy and loss progression:
[image]

What would you consider the best epoch to use before the model starts overfitting?

The purple one? (epoch #39 - where the loss appears to decrease its decline, contributing to an increase in the gap between training and validation)?

The orange one? (epoch #84 - lowest loss before stagnation)

Or another point?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to put it to use just like that then overfitting shouldn't be the main point here, the best result(val-loss in this case) is more important.
But if you want to re-train it then you better try both.

BTW 8 layers of FC layer!! That seem too many in my eyes, don't you have any gradient vanishing problem?

Comment: So, from what I understand, you would choose the best result, which would be the lowest validation loss - in this case the orange line - epoch 84, is that correct?

Answer (score 0):

the iterations number is not considered as a real problem on overfitting your model, you should choose the better one.

to elemenate the overfitting you should use cross validation, regularization, feauture selection ...

Comment: Are you saying that overfit is a only problem of architecture and not also of excessive training?